# rqt_gui error in perspective manager in ROS noetic

Tags: ros, rqt-gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run my code flawlessly in ROS Melodic but in ROS Noetic, I am having the following error (maybe because of python3):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/rqt_gui/rqt_gui", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main.main())
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_gui/main.py", line 61, in main
    return super(
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/main.py", line 614, in main
    perspective_manager.import_perspective_from_file(
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/perspective_manager.py", line 360, in import_perspective_from_file
    self._convert_values(data, self._import_value)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/perspective_manager.py", line 422, in _convert_values
    self._convert_values(groups[group], convert_function)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/perspective_manager.py", line 422, in _convert_values
    self._convert_values(groups[group], convert_function)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/perspective_manager.py", line 422, in _convert_values
    self._convert_values(groups[group], convert_function)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/perspective_manager.py", line 419, in _convert_values
    keys[key] = convert_function(keys[key])
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/perspective_manager.py", line 429, in _import_value
    return QByteArray.fromHex(eval(value['repr(QByteArray.hex)']))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QByteArray(): too many arguments
  QByteArray(int, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  QByteArray(Union[QByteArray, bytes, bytearray]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

Any idea on this? Or have you encountered this before?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365220/rqt_gui-error--in-perspective-manager-in-ros-noetic/) by [abata](https://answers.ros.org/users/56778/abata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-11-10

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikessut](https://answers.ros.org/users/63077/mikessut/) on 2020-11-11**:
I'm hitting exact same error with `rqt`.  I'm able to get it to run by changing /opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/perspective_manager.py:429 to `return value['repr(QByteArray.hex)']`. Still get a bunch of errors, but it at least runs.

**Comment by [abata](https://answers.ros.org/users/56778/abata/) on 2020-11-11**:
My launch file was using a `.perspective` file.  Also, when I tried to load it manually in `rqt`.  The same errors happened.  It was not necessary for me to load that file, then I modified the launch file :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I also encountered the same problem when porting some existing code to the ROS `noetic`.

In my case I had a `launch` file which invoked `rqt_gui` with a so-called perspective file, like this:

```
<node name="rqt_gui" pkg="rqt_gui" 
type="rqt_gui" respawn="false" 
args="--perspective-file $(find cyton_gamma_300_gazebo)/config/gazebo_effort_controller.perspective"/>
```

The *perspective file* in turn looked similar to the following:

```
    ..., "mainwindow": {
  "keys": {
    "geometry": {
      "type": "repr(QByteArray.hex)", 
      "repr(QByteArray.hex)": "QtCore.QByteArray('01d9d')", 
      "pretty-print": "     :     I :     I     "
    }, 
    "state": {
      "type": "repr(QByteArray.hex)", 
      "repr(QByteArray.hex)": "QtCore.QByteArray('000000ff')", 
      "pretty-print": "                 Lrqt_topic__TopicPlugin__1__TopicWidget          Xrqt_publisher__Publisher__1__PublisherWidget                            6MinimizedDockWidgetsToolbar        "
    }
  }, ....
```

We are interested in the `key`-`value` pairs looking similar to the following:

```
"repr(QByteArray.hex)": "QtCore.QByteArray('000000ff')",
```

and change it to the following:

```
"repr(QByteArray.hex)": "b'000000ff'",
```

I.e. after replacing the value with **only** byte content, like `b'000000ff'` and removing `QtCore.QByteArray()` creation, the `rqt_gui` is able to start without errors. No patching of `noetic` code required. Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [selyunin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30011/selyunin/) with karma: 96 on 2021-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [M Usamah Shahid](https://answers.ros.org/users/68924/m-usamah-shahid/) on 2021-01-29**:
This worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot